# Delete a row in Google Spreadsheets if color of cell is a certain color

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

So I've be racking my brain about this one for a while now, not 100% sure why this code isn't working.

I got the code from a previous SO post, from there I changed the script to do what I needed.

```
function onOpen() {
  // get active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // create menu
  var menu = [{name: "Evaluate Column J/Call Duration", functionName: "deleteRow"}];

  // add to menu
  ss.addMenu("Delete Calls Under 1 Minute", menu);
}

function deleteRow() {
  // get active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

 // get active/selected row
  var activeRow = ss.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();

  // get content column J
  var columnJ = ss.getRange("J"+activeRow).getFontColor();

  // evaluate whether cell has white text or not
  if (columnJ == 'white' || columnJ == '#FFFFFF') {
    ss.deleteRow(parseInt(activeRow));
  }
}
```

Basically I have a spreadsheet that's exported from a super archaic call tracking software. Our main issue is that we need to take out any call that's under 1 minute and any duplicates. So, we added conditional formatting for both. This is for getting rid of any 1 minute calls, which in turn should delete the whole row.

Anyone have any idea about this? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

Column j is 10. Colors are in '#ffffff' format. Red is '#ff0000'.  This function will delete the row that has the selected color in the selected column.

```
  function jakeDeleteRow(column,color) {
  var column = (typeof(column)!='undefined')?column:10;
  var color = (typeof(color)!='undefined')?color:'#ff0000; 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = ss.getDataRange();
  var rngA = rng.getBackgrounds()
  for(var i=rngA.length-1;i>-1;i--)
  {
    if(rngA[i][column-1]==color)
    {
      sht.deleteRow(i+1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When deleting rows such as this, it is much better to start at the end. As is, once a row is deleted the remaining rows will be misaligned and the next row deleted will be the wrong row.

Comment: @ScampMichael yes your correct.  I was just thinking about 1.  We've had a similar problem like this before.

Comment: @ScampMichael Thanks for you assistance.

Comment: @Cooper I tried running it and it just deletes all of the lines. Doesn't there need to be something in the script that calls what column or color it's looking for? Thanks!

Comment: You need to supply with two parameters column and color?